# Getting physical path of file in project directory

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am using `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to get the current directory, i.e. **"D:\Chuttu\Projects\LIC\bin\Debug"**

But, I want to remove **"\bin\Debug"**

How can I do that? Or is there any way so that I can get the directory up to **"LIC\"**?

Actually this is my connection string:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\LIC.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

But when I use this and try to insert data into the DB, the data is not inserted. When I use the connection string with a physical path it starts working:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Chuttu VB\Projects\LIC\LIC.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

I am trying to get the physical path of the `mdf` file and use it in the connection string.

---

EDIT:

This piece of code works fine:

```
Private Sub save()
        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Chuttu VB\Projects\LIC\LIC.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")

        Dim sql As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ProposerDetails " & _
                                            "VALUES (" & Convert.ToInt32(PolicyNumberTextBox.Text) & ",'" & NameTextBox.Text & "','" & AgeTextBox.Text & "','" & PhoneTextBox.Text & "','" & AddressTextBox.Text & "','" _
                                            & NomineeTextBox.Text & "','" & NomineeRelationTextBox.Text & "'," & PlanID() & ",'" & PolicyTermTextBox.Text & "','" & PremiumAmountTextBox.Text & "','" _
                                            & PremiumTypeComboBox.Text & "','" & SumProposedTextBox.Text & "','Date' )", con)

        MsgBox(sql.CommandText)
        con.Open()

        MsgBox(con.State.ToString)
        Dim i As Integer = sql.ExecuteNonQuery
        MsgBox(i.ToString)
        con.Close()
        sql.Dispose()
        con.Dispose()
        ToolStripStatusLabelMessage.Text = "Saved"
    End Sub
```

As soon as I change the connection string to the connection string from app.config it stops working (adding data to DB):

```
Private Sub save()
        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\LIC.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")

        Dim sql As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ProposerDetails " & _
                                            "VALUES (" & Convert.ToInt32(PolicyNumberTextBox.Text) & ",'" & NameTextBox.Text & "','" & AgeTextBox.Text & "','" & PhoneTextBox.Text & "','" & AddressTextBox.Text & "','" _
                                            & NomineeTextBox.Text & "','" & NomineeRelationTextBox.Text & "'," & PlanID() & ",'" & PolicyTermTextBox.Text & "','" & PremiumAmountTextBox.Text & "','" _
                                            & PremiumTypeComboBox.Text & "','" & SumProposedTextBox.Text & "','Date' )", con)

        MsgBox(sql.CommandText)
        con.Open()

        MsgBox(con.State.ToString)
        Dim i As Integer = sql.ExecuteNonQuery
        MsgBox(i.ToString)
        con.Close()
        sql.Dispose()
        con.Dispose()
        ToolStripStatusLabelMessage.Text = "Saved"
    End Sub
```

NOTE: I get no errors.

Comment: First of all the path of that you are showing is correct.. because it always displays the path of where the application is launched from.. make sense..? I would suggest putting things like SqlConnection String into the app.config file or what ever .config file you are using. here is a great site for how to format your connection strings http://www.dofactory.com/Connect/Connect.aspx also move the path / location of the MDF file

Comment: After your update you've introduced a new set of "those-are-really-bad-ideas" -- SQL injection proneness, inline SQL, hard-coded connection string, lack of the `using` statement. I think you're attempting to fix the wrong problem. A little refactoring could go a long ways.

Comment: @Cory when i use app.config connection string...the data does not save to the DB.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
string dataDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Reference:

- [`BaseDirectory` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: this gets me into the debug directory...i want the root directory.

Comment: But once you deploy your application the path will be correct. Visual Studio runs the code from the `Debug` or `Release` folder; that *is* the base directory. You could turn on "Copy to output directory" on your .mdf file, or create a setting with the path to your database and use that instead of hard-coding it if you need to persist your database changes while testing.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're going to want your final executable to navigate up two directories to find its database?  Also, newer versions of Windows are demanding admin privledges to write to you applications own folder in c:\Program Files.  Apparently, they want you storing stuff in c:\ProgramData or so.

Comment: MsgBox() out your two connection strings and see how they look?  Are you relying on your DB engine to decode |DataDirectory| ?  How does that get set and is it working right?   BTW, the guys talking about sql injection are right too. It doesn't help you solve today's issue but it is a concern  (see http://xkcd.com/327/ )

Answer (score 1):

Go to properties on your MDF file within visual studio (assuming you have it added as part of the project).  Set the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer".  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx for more information.

EDIT: Just to clarify that this does not get your base directory, it just makes sure that your database ends up in the folder with your executable, so relative paths will work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an issue with your connection string.  The issue is that every time you run your application, it uses a fresh copy of your mdf that is included in your project.  Take a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2007/05/29/working-with-a-local-data-file-in-vs.aspx) about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is to answer your question about the current path or directory of your project. You can use the REPLACE function to remove the "\bin\Debug\" part like this:

`Dim path As String
path = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
Dim path1 As String = path.Replace("\bin\Debug", "\")`